# RPi as wifi hotspot problem

Tags: networking, wifi

I need to connect my android mobile phone to my RPi through wifi so i did some search online and found [this](http://andypi.co.uk/?page_id=220) tried both the automatic way and the manual one provided in the link, and the RPi started to broadcast its wifi! but the problem is when i connect any device to it.. my android phone stucks at "obtaining ip address" and my pc shows troubleshoot the problem, and then the RPi wifi network disappears!
another issue in my case that after establishing the hotspot i can't connect to my Rpi via SSH over ethernet cable! 
so any link or advice to make my RPi broadcast its wifi? (i don't need it to connect me to the internet, just a local wifi network)

Comment: Is the hotspot setup to use DHCP?

Comment: yes it does. following another similar tutorial the udhcpd service works fine but the hostapd fails to start :/

Comment: What WiFi adapter do you have? Does it support AP mode under Linux? Not all adapters do, even if they work otherwise. Look at the output from hostapd, and post it here if it looks interesting (run hostapd in a terminal with the flag `-d` or `-dd` for debug info). I wrote a [blogpost](http://itsacleanmachine.blogspot.com/2013/02/wifi-access-point-with-raspberry-pi.html) about this some time ago, might still help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar situation, hostapd and udhcpd, and it turned out both my Android phone and MacBook were rejecting the DHCP offer from udhcpd because I didn't have any DNS servers configured in udhcpd.conf.

I don't need DNS on this network - this AP isn't a gateway, just a standalone device I need to ssh to every now and then - but once I put in:

```
opt     dns     127.0.0.1
```

both Android and OS X connected fine.